# How to select only those rows from the table, two columns of which aren't duplicated in that table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's rough example of what I need to accomplish for better understanding:

**SampleTable**

```
PrimaryKey SpecialCol1 RandomCol SpecialCol2
    1         aaa       sample1     111
    2         aaa       sample2     222
    3         bbb       sample3     444
    4         aaa       sample4     111
    5         ccc       sample5     444
    6         bbb       sample6     444
```

Final result should look like this:

```
PrimaryKey SpecialCol1 RandomCol SpecialCol2
--------------------------------------------
2         aaa       sample2     222
5         ccc       sample5     444
```

So I just need to select those rows for which combination of SpecialCol1 and SpecialCol2 is unique in that table. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how it can be done but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in stages.

1. Find the rows where the combination of columns is unique:

   ```
   SELECT SpecialCol1, SpecialCol2
     FROM SampleTable -- Thank you for invcluding the tablename
    GROUP BY SpecialCol1, SpecialCol2
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
   ```
2. Find the other details for the matching rows:

   ```
   SELECT s.*
     FROM SampleTable AS s
     JOIN (SELECT SpecialCol1, SpecialCol2
             FROM SampleTable -- Thank you for invcluding the tablename
            GROUP BY SpecialCol1, SpecialCol2
           HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
          ) AS t
       ON t.SpecialCol1 = s.SpecialCol1 AND t.SpecialCol2 = s.SpecialCol2;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MIN(primarykey), specialcol1, MIN(randomcol), specialcol2 
FROM sampletable 
GROUP BY specialcol1, specialcol2 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  SELECT   PrimaryKey
            ,SpecialCol1
            ,RandomCol
            ,SpecialCol2  
    FROM (( SELECT   SpecialCol1+SpecialCol2 AS test
                    ,PrimaryKey
                    ,SpecialCol1
                    ,RandomCol
                    ,SpecialCol2  
            FROM table)) AS temp 
    WHERE test IN (SELECT test 
                    FROM ( SELECT SpecialCol1+SpecialCol2 AS test 
                           FROM table) AS temp 
                           GROUP BY test 
                           HAVING COUNT(test)=1 )
```